# LOAD DATA INFILE hundreds of warnings for same row

Tags: mysql, warnings, load-data-infile

Importing a CSV file to mySQL via LOAD DATA INFILE....

Silly question but when viewing `SHOW WARNINGS;`output and getting responses back like the ones below, is it referring to Row 112 in the CSV file, or Row 112 in the database table?

```
  Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_track_qty' at row 112 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'album_disc_num' at row 112               |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'album_disc_num' at row 112               |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'album_disc_num' at row 112               |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_year' at row 112      |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_track_qty' at row 112 |
```

My table only has 7 columns, but it's reported 1126 warnings and they are ALL for Row 112! (I set `max_error_count = 1130;` so I could see them all). Any ideas why they would repeat so many times for the same row? The majority are Code 1366.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have row numbers in tables, so it must be referring to the file. I don't know why it's reporting the same line over and over, though.

Comment: Does line 112 of the file look OK?

Comment: It is referring to 112 character in every line of your file. It seems there is invalid character in the line, so it is giving 1366 error. If my assumption is right your album_year is an integer but the data provided is string which is present at 112 column of your file. (mysql error 1366 incorrect integer value)

Comment: @Barmar row 112 of the file and the 112th row in the MySQL table both looked fine... but in another import i've just done, it's flagged 'row 759' for being longer than VARCHAR() field length, and that is DEFINITELY talking about row 759 in the **table**. But it has also listed this warning about 25 times, I'd have expected 5 at the most (due to ignoring 4 duplicates), so I still don't follow the volume of warnings either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your album_year is an integer but you are trying to provide '' for that column. 
Try using 0 instead of '' for album_year.

Comment: thanks for this - it solved part of the problem by cutting down on a third of the warnings or so. I had album_year in my CSV formatted as 'Number' (since I want album_year to be a `YEAR` field type), but it seems this was the problem?? I changed the CSV to 'General' format, reimported and this time it's fine. Does this result make sense to you please?